# How can I test that a specific SSH key (a github deploy key specific to a repo) is valid?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have minted the keys and stored the public key in the deploy keys settings of the target repo.

When I minted the keys I sent them to `~/.ssh/my-repo` and `~/.ssh/my-repo.pub`. In my `~/.ssh/config` file I have updated it,

```
Host *.github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-repo
```

However, when I try to clone the repo via SSH I get prompted to enter my passphrase for `.../.ssh/id_ed25519`, which is my default SSH key. I know this one works. I'd like to test the one I minted specifically for `my-repo`.

Thanks for any pointers.

The end goal is to have a remote server clone the repo using this deploy key. At the moment it's hitting a Permission denied (public key) issue.

Update:

When using the command below,

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-repo git clone git@github.com:user/my-repo.git`

I get a timeout,

`ssh: connect to host git port 22: Operation timed out`

Comment: I have gone through the steps to add my ssh key to the mac OS keychain so that it no longer prompts for it. But how do I know it's using the right one?

Comment: Can you add the Git command you're using to clone the repo to your question?  To be sure that the code is using the right key, you could temporarily rename any key files that you think it might be using instead.  I guess this could be complicated by you having added keys to your Keychain.  I'm on a Mac, but I never involve my Mac's Keychain in any of this sort of thing.

Comment: I was doing a regular git clone with ssh. I have tried (updated post) `ssh -i` to specify an identity and now the connection times out.

Comment: Just reran a few times and sometimes it times out and sometimes it says `Connection refused`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh: connect to host git port 22: Operation timed out
                ^^^^^^^^
```

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-repo git clone git@github.com:user/my-repo.git` does not run a git command over ssh. It tries to ssh into the hostname `git`. That host doesn't exist, so it times out.

Instead, follow the instructions in [Testing your SSH connection](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection).

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

---

Your ssh configuration `Host *.github.com` does not match `github.com`; it would match `something.github.com`. Try `Host github.com`.

In addition, AddKeysToKeychain and Usekeychain probably shouldn't be restricted to a particular host.

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes

Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-repo
```

Comment: This worked after I `--unset` the osx keychain. I guess it was reaching for it despite the config pointing to a specific identity.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a Host entry different from github.com, precisely to make unambiguous the fact you are using a custom SSH URL:

```
Host gh
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-repo
```

Then your test becomes

```
ssh -Tv gh
```

And your URL becomes:

```
git clone gh:me/myRepo
```

No more `git@...`, since since the config file includes `User git`.